# Error when using Generic with Class<?> parameter

Tags: java, generics, reflection, enums

Got some problem when using Generic with Enum:

```
enum MyEnum1 {
    // ...
    public static MyEnum fromString(String enumStr) { /* ... */ }
}

enum MyEnum2 {
    // ...
    public static MyEnum fromString(String enumStr) { /* ... */ }
}

enum MyEnum3 {
    // ...
    public static MyEnum fromString(String enumStr) { /* ... */ }
}

class MyClass {
    Map<Class<? extends Enum<?>, EnumSet<? extends Enum<?>>> map;

    public <E extends Enum<E>> void addValue2EnumSet(Class<E> enumType, E value)；

    // enumType and valueStr is of the same length
    public static Map<Class<? extends Enum<?>, EnumSet<? extends Enum<?>>> getMapOfEnumSet(Class<? extends Enum<?>>[] enumTypes, String[] valueStrs) {
        MyClass c = // ...
        for (int i = 0; i < enumTypes.length; ++i) {
            // for each enumType and valueStr pair
            // add the value (= Enum1/2/3.fromString(valueStr)) to the Map
            Class<? extends Enum<?>> enumType = enumTypes[i];
            String valueStr = valueStrs[i];
            Method fromStringMethod = enumType.getDeclaredMethod("fromString", String.class);

            // error!
            c.addValue2EnumSet(enumType, enumType.cast(fromStringMethod.invoke(null, valueStr))); 
        }
        return c.map;
    }
}
```

In this line `c.addValue2EnumSet(enumType, enumType(fromStringMethod.invoke(null, valueStr)));`, an compile-error is the second parameter, `Found: 'java.lang.Enum<?>`, required: '? extends java.lang.Enum'`

How to call `addValue2EnumSet()` in `getEnumSetOf()`?

In this case, a `Class<? extends Enum<?> enumType` parameter is passed, and it is used to judge which kind of Enum (Enum1/2/3) is the target, then call the `fromString()` method to generate the corresponding Enum instance. I have no idea but the reflection to get methods from the enumType.

The difficult is that the two parameters of `getEnumSetOf` are arrays, and each element in the first param, e.g., `enumTypes[0]`, choose the corresponding Enum Type of second param, e.g., `valueStrs[0]`. That is to say, the target type of `valueStrs[0]` is `enumTypes[0]`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not quite sure why you are using generics - perhaps you could explain further.

On the assumption that you want to build sets of enums from a seed via a string name you may find this technique usable. The critical part of this is using the [Enum.getDeclaringClass()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Enum.html#getDeclaringClass%28%29) method.

```
enum ABEnum {

    A, B;

    public static ABEnum fromString(String enumStr) {
        return ABEnum.valueOf(enumStr);
    }
}

public static Enum fromString(Enum seed, String enumStr) throws Exception {
    Class declaringClass = seed.getDeclaringClass();
    Method fromStringMethod = declaringClass.getDeclaredMethod("fromString", String.class);
    Object result = fromStringMethod.invoke(null, enumStr);
    return (Enum) result;
}

public void test() throws Exception {
    Enum e = fromString(ABEnum.A, "B");
    System.out.println(e);
}
```

This seems to go further towards your scenario - it builds a map much like yours by reflection. Perhaps it will help.

```
enum ABEnum {

    A, B, E;

    public static ABEnum fromString(String enumStr) {
        return ABEnum.valueOf(enumStr);
    }
}

enum CDEnum {

    C, D, E;

    public static CDEnum fromString(String enumStr) {
        return CDEnum.valueOf(enumStr);
    }
}

public static Enum fromString(Enum seed, String enumStr) throws Exception {
    Class declaringClass = seed.getDeclaringClass();
    Method fromStringMethod = declaringClass.getDeclaredMethod("fromString", String.class);
    Object result;
    try {
        result = fromStringMethod.invoke(null, enumStr);
    } catch (InvocationTargetException e) {
        result = null;
    }
    return (Enum) result;
}

Map<Class, EnumSet> map = new HashMap<>();

public void test() throws Exception {
    //Enum e = fromString(ABEnum.A, "B");
    Enum[] enums = new Enum[]{ABEnum.A, CDEnum.C};
    String[] names = new String[]{"A", "B", "C", "D", "E"};
    for (Enum e : enums) {
        Class c = e.getClass();
        for (String s : names) {
            EnumSet set = map.get(c);
            if (set == null) {
                map.put(c, set = EnumSet.noneOf(c));
            }
            Enum found = fromString(e, s);
            if (found != null) {
                set.add(found);
            }
        }
    }
    System.out.println(map);
}
```

Comment: I need a Enum hierarchy which means an object can have many kind of Enum types, stored in `Map<Class<? extends Enum<?>>, EnumSet<? extends Enum<?>>> map;`, with different Enum, e.g., `Enum1`, the object have a type of `Enum1.VALUE2`. The method `fromString()` just follows the way from Generic chapter of "Effective Java", which would get no exception and can get costumed String content. Anyway, thank you for your solution of `fromString()`.

Comment: @stanleyerror - I've added some more examples. In general, using `?` in generics almost certainly does **not** do what you want it to do.